# Can i keep a task definition active, even after my Java job is completed when using docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, amazon-ecs

I have an application that i run through docker file. Is it possible for me to keep the task definition active even if the application in it gets killed.

Docker File sample

```
FROM <domain>:<port>/<package_name>/<image_nmae>
ADD target/<app_jar>.jar /app.jar
ADD lib/* /lib/
ADD log4j2.xml /lib/
ADD <some_script>.sh /setup.sh 
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/setup.sh"]
```

Comment: yes. dont make parent process which is being killed after completion. start that process using supervisord or systemctl etc. so your container will be active even if the process killed.

Comment: ok, but below is the docker file i am using

FROM <domain>:<port>/<package_name>/<image_nmae>
ADD target/<app_jar>.jar /app.jar
ADD lib/* /lib/
ADD log4j2.xml /lib/
ADD <some_script>.sh /setup.sh 
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/setup.sh"]

Comment: so process start by setup.sh killed, the container will be killed.

Comment: i want to keep it active even though the setup.sh completes

Comment: then remove setup.sh from cmd and run setup.sh after container boot or put setupsh.sh to run by supervisord or share your proper docker file so i will share detail answer

Comment: thanks adiii, Thats the actual docker file in the question above. Also fyi, setup.sh will only trigger the application (java app)

Answer (score 0):

yep task definition is like the docker run command with options so it's only a config. you only get billed for ec2 or fargate usage and first 500mb of ECR free